# OAuth 2.0 Scope parameter vs OAuth 2.0 JWT access_token scope claim

Tags: security, oauth, oauth-2.0, jwt, auth0

I was going through the following article on authorization:

https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/aspnet-core-webapi/02-authorization

It sort of confused me a bit.

Auth0 uses a scope claim for mentioning authorization of endpoint actions.

OAuth 2.0 scope parameter is also used for the same purpose, e.g. Slack mentions it's scopes as in following link:

https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth-scopes

What would be their use cases, when would I prefer using JWT claim scope which is part of OAuth 2.0 access_token(in this case access_token not being opaque) instead of OAuth 2.0 scope parameter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OAuth 2.0 scope parameter is defined within the specification as a way for the client application request specific access and then be informed by the authorization server which access was indeed granted.

Both scenarios you mentioned seem pretty consistent with this use case; a way to specify the access/permissions you were granted.

The big difference is that in one case by-value tokens (JWT) are being used and the other uses by-reference tokens (opaque). If the token is self-contained as it is in the case of the JWT you will have to include the information within it and the claim they used was the `scope` claim.

In summary, the `scope` parameter is a way to transmit the access you require and the access you were indeed granted. This information will also need to be stored in association with the issued access token. If it's a JWT, it will most likely be stored in the token itself; if it's an opaque token it will most likely be stored server-side.

Comment: so you mean the scope parameter has one to one correspondence with scope claim, scope claim comes into existence after access_token is created, and scope parameter is used to request these claims, and then either stored in JWT(stateless) access_token or stored in server in case of opaque access token

Comment: I would mostly agree with that interpretation; I wouldn't go so far as to say it's a one to one correspondence as you may request a certain amount of scopes, but you then only get granted a subset of the scopes you requested. Besides that, yes, the claim is just way to keep track of the scopes that were granted within the token itself.